# Fatal Error Call To Undefined Method Stack Trace:#0

Tags: php, database

Source of the problem: `$db -> listOccurrences();`

I tried this:

```
public function listAbsences()
    {
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT description FROM records WHERE _ID_Record_Type = 1;"
        $sqlquery = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery) > 0){
            $result = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) {
                $result[] = '$row["description"];
            }
            return $result;
        }
        $this->close_connect();
    }
```

And this:

```
public function listAbsences()
    {
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT description FROM records WHERE _ID_Record_Type = 1;"
        $sqlquery = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery) > 0){
            $result = array();
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) {
                $result[] = '<li class="list-group-item">'.$row["description"].'</li>';
            }
            return $result;
        }
        $this->close_connect();
    }
```

And this:

```
public function listAbsences()
    {
        $this->connect();
        $sql = "SELECT description FROM records WHERE _ID_Record_Type = 1;"
        $sqlquery = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($sqlquery) > 0){
            $result = "";
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqlquery)) {
                $result .= "<li class='list-group-item'>".$row["description"]."</li>";
            }
            echo $result;
        }
        $this->close_connect();
    }
```

But I've kept having the same error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method db::listOccurrences() in C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\start.php:39 Stack trace:#0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\start.php on line 39

Comment: Where is line 39 of `start.php` in your code above? *Programming 101: The error message tells you very good information, read it carefully.*  What does the variable `$db` contain? It's probably a class you've written, but you haven't shared enough context with us.  But that class needs to have a function titled `listOccurrences()`....

Comment: I don't see `listOccurrences ` anywhere in your listed code. Check your code to see where you're attempting to use it.